# Gdb step through assembly output of objdump from C compiled

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, x86

I have a binary executable compiled by gcc on an IA32. It was originally coded in C. I would like to be able to step through and debug it. I can run objdump and shovel that to a file to read.

```
objdump -d mybinary > mytext.txt
```

I would like to be able to step through the assembly lines that I can see through objdump. I have used gdb a little bit and I would like to be able to run gdb on the output of an objdump. Is this possible or is there a good way to do this? What I'm thinking in my head is trying to do the following which obviously doesn't work.

```
objdump -d mybinary > gdb
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or show me how to get my binary in a form where I can use it with gdb?

Comment: Why can't up you just `gdb mybinary`?

Comment: Can't you recompile the source code with `gcc -Wall -g` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to be able to run gdb on the output of an objdump

That request makes no sense whatsoever.

What you are probably asking is "can I single-step in GDB, one instruction at a time?", in which case the answer is yes: use `stepi` command.