# How to execute a disassembled ELF instruction by instruction?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, elf

I need to do some observations on a disassembled ELF and for that i kind of need to execute the program instruction by instruction (disassembled). Including the part the part where it jumps to other ELF sections like .plt or .got. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Why don't you execute the elf itself instruction by instruction? gdb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gdb step through assembly output of objdump from C compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516340/gdb-step-through-assembly-output-of-objdump-from-c-compiled)

Comment: I understood that doing that with gdb will not lead me through all the jumps, meaning jumps to .plt or .got will be ignored and execution will continue.

Comment: Use `stepi` (or `si` for short) to single-step *by machine instruction*.  Using that, nothing is ever skipped.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB tips, e.g. `layout reg`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you get a tool like [gef](https://github.com/hugsy/gef) to help make your gdb output pretty and then you step through the program with `si` in order to go instruction by instruction and take every jump, even into the plt and external libraries such as libc.